# how can i parser out my phone number by cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

my html liks:

```
<dl class="resume_pro">  
    <dt>    <h3>personal infomation</h3>  </dt>  
    <dd class="pro_lf"> 
        <span class="rt_title">sex:male | age:26 </span>
        <div class="clear"></div> 
        <br>phone:123456789<a href="###" class="send" id="sendsms" style="display:none">send message</a><br>   E-mail：name@abc.com <br>  
    </dd>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</dl>
```

my parser code :

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
found = $('*:contains("phone:")').last();
```

the found will get "`<dd class="pro_lf"> </dd>`"

and then found.text() will get "`sex:male | age:26 phone:123456789send message   E-mail：name@abc.com` "

but how can i get each phone and e-mail?

i wanna to write a code in common use

so i just used  `$('*:contains("phone:")')` to search my infomation, not use tag name or class name

i will loop the element to find out every last node and get content to parser

i need some help.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but your selector is *extremely* inefficient. Consider putting the phone number in a separate `div` with its own unique ID so you don't have to scrape the entire DOM to get it. Something like `<span id="myPhoneNumber">Phone:123456789</span>` should be sufficient, and you can reference it with `$('#myPhoneNumber')`.

Comment: @DesertIvy first of all to thank your for your comment. the html is not wrote by me. it's got by other program and be saved a html file, i just need to parser it. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use this to loop over each element:

```
found.contents().each(function() {
.....
});
```

Then you can use a regex in the loop in order to get the phone number.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your provided example (missing a `);` at the end of your `each` call). Also, for other users' reference, please post the regular expression you used in your loop. Right now, this does not provide a sufficient answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a thousand ways to do this, but here's a succinct way using a regular expression (of which I am no master, but here's my take):

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
found = $('*:contains("phone:")').last();

//Find phone number
var phoneNumber = str.match(/phone\:\d+/)[0].match(/\d+$/);
```

The `match` will find the string `"phone:123456789"` and return it in an array with only one element. Then we split the string where `"phone:"` appears, leaving the array `["", "123456789"]`.

To expand on the RegEx `/phone\:\d+/`:

```
/                   start of regex
 phone\:            match the string literal, "phone:"
 \d+                match 1 or more digits following "phone:"
/                   end of regex
```

And for `/\d+$/`:

```
/                   start of regex
 \d+                match 1 or more digits
 $                  ...at the end of the string
/                   end of regex
```

After running this, `phoneNumber` will be the string `"123456789"`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. your mean that i should use Regex to match the `fount.text()`? the fount.text() will take all of content which in tag <dd>, if the content be join each other with no " ", i think it's gonna be a hard work.

Comment: If you ran the code, you should see that `phoneNumber` is `"123456789"`. Please try it and report back. This should give you the result you want.

Comment: i found a simple way to do this